# how to install nginx after removed it manually

Tags: nginx

I have installed `nginx` using `apt`

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Then I used `whereis nginx` and removed all files manually using `rm`  now I wanna re-install `nginx` but it doesn't work and returning error:

```
awk: cannot open /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (No such file or directory)
```

I create `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`  then use `apt-get install nginx` it installed completely doesn't work.

output of `sudo dpkg -l | grep nginx`:

```
ii  nginx                                      1.4.3-1~raring0                        all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server
ii  nginx-common                               1.4.3-1~raring0                        all          small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files
ii  nginx-full                                 1.4.3-1~raring0                        i386         nginx web/proxy server (standard version)
```

Comment: The way you used to remove `nginx` was not the correct way to remove any package in ubuntu. You'd to remove it using same `apt-get` command. Let me post the proper way to remove it completely and and how to install it again.

Comment: i know that lately but how i can fix it know  and i do the same for remove apatch2

Comment: April, please check my answer once. Also try to re-start your system once with still it doesn't work!

Comment: its not work and whereis nginx return nothing

Answer (score 20):

**Since you managed to install it anyhow first thing you've to do is to remove it completely with the configuration files**

Follow these steps to remove it completely and install it again.

- Open terminal and execute these commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoremove nginx
  sudo apt-get --purge remove nginx
  sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
  sudo find / | grep nginx | sudo xargs rm -rf
  ```

  <sub>the last command will remove the repository also so you've to add it again by:</sub>

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nginx/stable
  ```

  Now try to install it again by:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -f install nginx
  ```
- Hope it would solve your issue. Reply if you get any error at any particular command describing the command.

This is the output of

`sudo dpkg -l | grep nginx`:

```
ii  nginx                                       1.4.3-1~precise0                                    small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server
ii  nginx-common                                1.4.3-1~precise0                                    small, powerful, scalable web/proxy server - common files
ii  nginx-full                                  1.4.3-1~precise0                                    nginx web/proxy server (standard version)
```

`whereis nginx`:

```
nginx: /usr/sbin/nginx /etc/nginx /usr/share/nginx /usr/share/man/man1/nginx.1.gz
```

Comment: Did you get any error message while installing `nginx`? Also post the output of this command in your question: `sudo dpkg -l | grep nginx`

Comment: every think seam okey  it must work but  i think i delete some system file when i write whereis nginx and delete all result

Comment: can you post output of whereis nginx ?

Comment: no errors only this warning 

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'nginx-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'nginx-full' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed


W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)

Comment: April, I've edited my answer..

Comment: April,  I think there is some `residual` packages left in your system. To insure this paste the output of this command: `sudo dpkg -l | grep "^rc"` Reply..

Comment: @EliahKagan I have noticed many time `sudo apt-get --purge remove` removed many unnecessary and unwanted files which had been installed at the time of package installation. You may say those as supportive packages. I just wrote purge to completely remove **nginx**. And it worked for me. Though if you have any suggestion you are most welcomed :) Thanks..

Comment: @SauravKumar Yes, I agree `sudo apt-get --purge remove ...` (or the equivalent `sudo apt-get purge ...`) can be helpful. But I'm not sure it always *does anything* if the package or package list being purged (which I've been calling `...`) has *already* been removed. Sometimes it does, but I seem to recall sometimes having to run `sudo dpkg -P ...` instead. Unfortunately I don't really have any alternatives or improvements to suggest: instead, I was hoping you (or someone else reading) might know if `sudo apt-get purge ...` always works for removing conffiles of already uninstalled packages.

Answer (score 12):

The problem you had is that you removed some files that don't belong to package `nginx`, the package that installs /etc/nginx files is `nginx-common`.

So if you want to recreate the `/etc/nginx` files, you should do:

```
> apt-get install --reinstall nginx-common
```

In order to determine to which package belongs a file, you should execute `dpkg -S <file>`, in this case:

```
dpkg -S /etc/nginx
nginx-common: /etc/nginx
```

Comment: This worked for me, so it gets my vote!